# How to make chrome open to a blank tab

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm running CM 10.1 on my Nexus S and it's definitely showing its age.  If I want to quickly google something I open up Chrome and then wait 15 seconds for it to load the last page, and then try and type in the location bar for 30 seconds as it freezes and then suddenly types my query out all at once.

My question is, how can I make Chrome open to a new blank tab each time I click its icon?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I imagine you could make a bookmark for `about:blank` and add the bookmark icon to your home screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Al Everett is correct. Use a shortcut on your launcher, because I do not see any options within the Chrome app to change your "home page".

Go to Bookmarks, add `about:blank` to Mobile bookmarks, navigate there, and then click and hold on the bookmark icon and select "Add to home screen". Presto.

Comment: I swear this used to work. Doesn't seem to work anymore, at least not for Android 5.1.1 (cyanogen 12.1) running Chrome 49.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Settings > Homepage to something like `chrome-native://newtab/`